# Autokey - put/remove a border around the whole screen/desktop?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autokey

**Clarification**: 
despite the tag, this is about ***AUTOKEY*** (the Linux hotkey automation app), not ***AUTOHOTKEY*** (exclusively for W10). There is no tag for Autokey. .... **correction, a day later**: ha, someone created it, thanks!

Using Auto***HOT***key in W10 I've managed to do this border thing. For the record, this is what the script looks like:

```
; added 2022-08-23: show a red border round desktop when the Greek Polytonic Keyboard is selected

#SingleInstance force

;#HotkeyModifierTimeout -1

$#space::
If (toggle := !toggle)
{
    Send, #{space}
    Sleep, 1000
    
    SysGet, Coord, MonitorWorkArea, 1
    Gui, Margin, 25,25
    Gui, Color, Red, EEAA99
    Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
    WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
    Gui, Add, ListBox
; ,% "w" CoordRight-600 " h" CoordBottom-500 " Disabled"
    ,% "w" 3000 " h" 1650 " Disabled"
    Gui, Show
    
    SetKeyDelay 30,50
    Send, {ALT DOWN}{TAB}{ALT UP}
    SetKeyDelay, 0
    

}
else {
    Send, #{space}
    Sleep, 1000
    
    Gui, Hide
}
return
```

... the purpose can be seen from the first line: when I toggle from my English-UK-extended keyboard to Greek Polytonic (uses the same key combo, Winkey-space), this puts an  unignorable red border all around my screen. Toggling back removes it.

This gives me a visual indicator, other than the tiny icon in the tray bar (NB very large monitor), of which keyboard I'm in.

I'd like to do the same in Autokey. The great thing about Autokey is that it uses Python as its scripting language. So I was hopeful that this wouldn't be too difficult. But in fact I have no idea how to do this: googling brings up suggestions relating to packages like Tkinter.

The Autokey documentation seems to include some tools for manipulating windows, e.g. [this](https://autokey.github.io/api/window.html), but nothing there that looks that promising.

Comment: There's script at https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator , as well as mention o gxneur. Also see https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enabling-the-keyboard-layout-indicator-with-country-flags/1256 . However, these just modify the small icon flag for layout.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really looking for something a bit more splashy. Could be a change of desktop background (for example), etc.